# textarea with angular material not size properly on launching page

Tags: angular, angular-material, textarea

I'm facing a weird issue that I cannot understand.
When one of my page is displaying I have my textarea cut as we can see in this image

[image]

But when I resize just a little the page or I just open the console (which probably resize the page too), the text appears completely

[image]

It's a form and I have the possibility to edit it, and when I do, and save, text appears completely too, the problem only happen when the page is just launched.

I use angular material and simple textarea like this :

```
 <textarea matInput
   cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
   cdkAutosizeMinRows="1" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="25"
 </textarea>
```

just for info it's inside a "ng-template" but don't think it changes anything.
I don't want to fix a specific height as you imagine because it should be dynamic depending on the text length.

Do you have any idea of where could it come from ? And how can I workaround it ?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue, solved it by leveraging the ChangeDetectorRef markForCheck() method after view is initialized.

in the constructor:

```
constructor(private changeDetRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

in the ngAfterViewInit code:

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.changeDetRef.markForCheck();
  }
```

make sure your class implements AfterViewInit, for example -

```
export class MyAwesomeComponent implements AfterViewInit
```

by the way, in my specific case i've been using OnPush change Detection strategy

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a hack which is not really beautiful in the end but work anyway.

I added a class on my textarea tag;
I've already had a "ngAfterViewInit" in my typescript class so inside :

```
const textArea = document.getElementsByClassName('text-area-class')[0];
const textAreaHeight = window.getComputedStyle(textArea).height;
const newHeight = (parseFloat(textAreaHeight.split('px')[0]) * 1.3);
txtArea.setAttribute('style', `height: ${newHeight}px`);
```

The value of 1.3 is arbitrary and just has been tested to fit the most with my needs.
I know it's not the most beautiful way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The core reason behind this why it's not working is that the `textarea` size is calculated before being rendered. Try removing the auto `height` property, and set a fixed `line-height` to it.

Example:

```
textarea {
  /*height: auto !important;*/
  resize: none;
  line-height: 3 !important;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Still the same even with line-height